# Use django-mptt to query the database for all root categories that have at least one subcategory and at least one product

Tags: django, django-mptt

I have a `Category` model and I use django-mptt to have subcategories (and sub-subcategories, etc.). I also have products, which are assigned to categories.

I want to query the database for all root categories that have at least one subcategory and at least one product. For example, consider this data structure:

```
Category: Dairy (0 subcategories, 1 product)
    Product: Milk
Category: Fruit (1 subcategory, 0 products)
    Subcategory: Red (0 subcategories, 0 products)
Category: Vegetables (1 subcategory, 0 products)
    Subcategory: Green (0 subcategories, 1 product)
        Product: Cucumber
Category: Junk Food (1 subcategory, 1 product)
    Product: Doritos
    Subcategory: Chocolate (0 subcategories, 1 product)
        Product: Snickers
```

In this case, I would want the query to return just the "Junk Food" category since it's the only one that matches all three criteria (root category, has at least one subcategory, has at least one product).

I looked through the django-mptt documentation, but didn't see a way to do this. Maybe I overlooked it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see your `Category` and `Product` models to get a better idea of your database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter on the many to one fields on Category for subcategories and products.
So perhaps something like:

```
Category.objects.filter(
    parent=None,  # must be root category
    children__in=Category.objects.filter(level=1),  # must have at least one sub-category
    products__in=Product.objects.all()  # must have at least one product
).distinct()
```

or

```
Category.objects.filter(
    parent=None,  # must be root category
    children__isnull=False,  # must have at least one sub-category
    products__isnull=False  # must have at least one product
).distinct()
```